# Forking process in C

Tags: c, process, fork, system

I have this code in the course of system programming I am following :

```
/* La fonction create_process duplique le processus appelant et retourne
   le PID du processus fils ainsi créé */
pid_t create_process(void)
{
    /* On crée une nouvelle valeur de type pid_t */
    pid_t pid;

    /* On fork() tant que l'erreur est EAGAIN */
    do {
    pid = fork();
    } while ((pid == -1) && (errno == EAGAIN));

    /* On retourne le PID du processus ainsi créé */
    return pid;
}

/* La fonction child_process effectue les actions du processus fils */
void child_process(void)
{
    printf(" We are in the son's process !\n"
       " son's pid is est %d.\n"
       " son's PPID is %d.\n", (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
}

/* La fonction father_process effectue les actions du processus père */
void father_process(int child_pid)
{
    printf(" We are in the father process !\n"
       "  son's PID is %d.\n"
       " father's PID is %d.\n", (int) child_pid, (int) getpid());
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = create_process();

    switch (pid) {
    /* Si on a une erreur irrémédiable (ENOMEM dans notre cas) */
    case -1:
    perror("fork");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    break;
    /* Si on est dans le fils */
    case 0:
    child_process();
    break;
    /* Si on est dans le père */
    default:
    father_process(pid);
    break;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of the function is :

We are in the father's process!
 son's PID is 6246.
 father's PID is 6245.
 We are in the son's process !
 son's PID is 6246.
 son's PPID is 1.

I dont understand why this code produces this output :
The function create_process forks a new process from the parent. So in the parent process the function create_process returns the child_process pid and I understand the first part :

```
We are in the father's process!
son's PID is 6246.
father's PID is 6245.
```

Then I guess the child_process is executing and the create_process function returns 0 because we are in the child_process now and I also understand the following output :

```
We are in the son's process!
son's PID is 6246.
son's PPID is 1.
```

But I dont understand why the execution stops after that... we are still forking the child process right ? So I feel like it should keep on creating new processes and printing:

```
We are in the son's process !
son's PID is OTHER.
son's PPID is 6246.
```

Could someone please explain to me why this code does not keep on creating processes

Comment: Not all of us speak French; it'd be nice if you translated the comments and strings.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 done

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    pid = fork();
} while ((pid == -1) && (errno == EAGAIN));
```

Assuming the call to `fork` is successful, it only gets called once.  So only one new process is created.  Then the child calls `child_process` and the parent calls `father_process`.  After that, they both return to the `main` function where they break out of the `switch` statement and return from `main`.

Comment: I understand what you say but before entering entering the switch the child process is executing create_process(); which (in my understanding) creates a new process (with the same code) which creates another child_process, which in turn will also create another child_process ... I dont understand how this code stops creating new processes...

Comment: @DavidGeismar First the parent calls `create_process`.  In this function, it calls `fork`.  This creates the child process, then **both** processes return from `fork`, with 0 being returned to the child and the child's pid being returned to the parent.  In both cases, the `while` loop exits and both processes return from `create_process`.